# UNIX to print a content from a .gz file

Tags: text-processing, gzip

I have a .gz file with contents like the following:

```
ID:123455   23-07-2015 mvni
warning: RTM post
warning : no profile data
```

Using the string `no profile data`, I want to print the ID. 
I tried with grep before and after lines but it's not working. Please suggest any other methods.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ zgrep -B2 'warning : no profile data' *.gz | grep -o '^ID:[0-9]*'
ID:123455
```

As pointed out by user3188445, `zgrep` will grep for strings within (possibly compressed) files. Using `-B2` to print 2 lines before the warning match, then extracting the IDs of all matching files using a standard `grep` against `stdout`.

This will work whether you have several compressed files, or several matching sections within the same file.

Comment: i tried using this command grep -B2 'warning :no profile data'* .gz but its not working .telling -B does not exist

Comment: In that case, I would suggest going with the second update of [user3188445's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/217895/124507), which should work with older versions of `zgrep` as well.

Comment: if i have to print only the number of ID . Means from ID:123455. I just want to print 123455

Comment: `zgrep -l 'warning : no profile data' *.gz | xargs zgrep '^ID:' | sed -e 's/^ID:\([0-9]*\) .*/\1/'`, as suggested by user3188445. That will work with your version of zgrep.

Answer (score 2):

The `zcat` command or `gzip -dc` will uncompress and print the output of a gzipped file to stdout.  So you can run, for example, `zcat file.gz | grep '^ID:'`.  However, most systems have a command called `zgrep` that already does that for you.

### update

Under the assumption that you have a bunch of these files, and want to print the ID line from files that contain a particular warning, you can do this:

```
zgrep -l 'warning : no profile data' *.gz | xargs zgrep '^ID:'
```

The first command, `zgrep -l`, prints a list of files that contain the warning.  The second command, `xargs`, takes a list of arguments on standard input and runs a command on all the inputs.  The command it runs is also `zgrep`, so as to print the ID line you want.

### Second update

To extract just the numeric ID, take the command I previously suggested and append

```
| sed -e 's/^ID:\([0-9]*\) .*/\1/'
```

That will just print the ID number.

Comment: i want to search first the keyword 'no profile data' then only to print the ID

Comment: Can you elaborate?  Do you have a bunch of these files, and you want to print the ID line from the files that have a warning?  Or does the file have multiple sections?

Comment: i am having bunch of these files . In these files where the warning come as no profile data . I have to print only the first section that is ID:123455

Comment: I assume by first section you mean first line?  If so, then does my update work?

Comment: in the first line , i need only the ID

Comment: Try again with the edited version: `zgrep -l 'warning : no profile data' *.gz | xargs zgrep -o '^ID:[0-9]*'`

Comment: if i have to print only the number of ID . Means from ID:123455. I just want to print 123455

Comment: Does the command I suggested not do that?

Comment: it will print ID:123455 but i want to print only 123455

Comment: Try getting rid of the space before the `.*` in the sed command.  Maybe your files contain a TAB instead of a space.

Comment: E.g., when I run `echo 'ID:123 blah blah' | sed -e 's/^ID:\([0-9]*\).*/\1/'`, it outputs `123`.

Comment: The contents of my .gz file is as below
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ID:342N000390AAAAAAAA   07/14/15 10:26      (MV90    )
      * Warning - No Profile Data
      * Register Data Imported
                           07/14/15 10:24  05/13/15 08:16       15    1   5956
---------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: I tried what you told but its not working

Comment: i tried this usr/contrib/bin/gzcat $DI | grep 'No Profile Data' | \
                        while read ID JUNK
                        do
                                    IID=`print $ID | cut -f2 -d ":"`
                                    if [ -n "$IID" ]
                                    then
                                                print "$IID" >> $TMP_RPT_FILE
 
                                    
                                    fi
                        done

Comment: the above code what i have written is not able to fetch the id

Comment: the options -B, -O telling as illegal options

Comment: Okay, I guess your IDs are not just numeric.  So try: `zgrep -l 'warning : no profile data' *.gz | xargs zcat | sed -ne 's/^ID:\([A-Z0-9]*\)[^A-Z0-9].*/\1/p'`

Comment: No its not working . I think after searching the keyword no profile data then it search for ID but it lies above the it due to which it is unable to get the id .what to do in this case?

Comment: Ah, you changed the capitalization compared to your example.  Try `zgrep -il 'no profile data' *.gz | xargs zcat | sed -ne 's/^ID:\([A-Z0-9]*\)[^A-Z0-9].*/\1/p'`

Comment: My OS is HP-UX . will this command will be working?

Answer (score 1):

You can use zgrep to grep a .gz file. I suspect you want something like:

```
zgrep -B 2 'warning : no profile data' file.gz
```

Comment: i tried this but its not working .Its telling that -B does not exist

Comment: Ah, perhaps your copy of zgrep is a little too simplistic. In which case, you might want to try: `zcat file.gz | grep -B 2 'warning : no profile data'`

Comment: No , its not working -B options invalid

Answer (score 1):

If  you have access to GNU utilities, this should work:

```
zgrep -B2 "no profile data" file | grep -oP 'ID:\K\d+'
```

If that doesn't work, you can try this instead:

```
zcat file.gz | grep -B2 "no profile data" | sed -n 's/ID:\([0-9]*\).*/\1/p'
```

Or:

```
zcat file.gz | 
 awk '{if(/^ID/){split($1,a,/:/); id=a[2];}if(/no profile data/){print id}}'
```

Or:

```
 zcat file.gz | perl -lne '$id=$1 if /^ID:(\d+)/; print $id if /no profile data/'
```

Comment: The contents of my .gz file is as below
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ID:342N000390AAAAAAAA   07/14/15 10:26      (MV90    )
      * Warning - No Profile Data
      * Register Data Imported
                           07/14/15 10:24  05/13/15 08:16       15    1   5956
---------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: i tried what you told but its not working