# How to print the before lines of search keyword with out using grep in a gz file?

Tags: text-processing, grep, gzip, hp-ux

How to print the lines before a search keyword without using `grep` in a .gz file?

```
ID:342N000390AAAAAAAA   07/14/15 10:26      (MV90    )
         * Register Data Imported
         * Warning - No Profile Data
     07/14/15 10:24  05/13/15 08:16       15    1   5956
```

I want to search the `No Profile` Keyword and print the ID NUMBER THAT IS 342N000390AAAAAAAA and necessarily "No Profile" won't come in third line; it may come in any line. My Operating system is HP-UX, so many commands are not eligible.

Comment: What's your OS?

Comment: Can you please run `grep --version` and try using `grep -C2` (**context**)?

Comment: Since  they are .gz files you  need to use `zgrep`

Comment: My OS HP-UX aehpdcds01 B.11.31 U ia64 0209983576 unlimited-user license

Comment: HPUX don't have the same `grep` as Linux; so you could build and install [GNU grep](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/), perhaps configured with `--prefix=$HOME/soft/`

Answer (score 3):

You could work with `awk` instead:

```
gzcat file.gz | awk '/No Profile Data/{printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n", b, a, $0} {b=a;a=$0}'
```

- `gzcat` (or `zcat` on Linux) prints the content of the gzipped file to the standard output
- `awk` then searches for the string `"No Profile Data"` and prints the two previous lines

Comment: I tried but its not printing the previous two lines

Comment: @Pooja Try now, I edited my answer

Comment: zcat IIRC on HP-UX only supports file.Z (ie compress) and not gzip

Comment: change zcat to 'gunzip -c'

Comment: Hi . It showing syntax error in this line { printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n", b, a, $0}

Comment: Can any one tell how to do this using find command

Comment: @Pooja On HP-UX use `gzcat` instead of `zcat`.

Answer (score 2):

### Edited

New approach: removing line breaks.

Assuming that you have only one ID per gzipped file, you can try the following:

```
gunzip -c file.gz | sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' -e '/^[[:space:]]/d' -e 's/^ID:\([[:alnum:]]*\).*Warning - No Profile Data.*/\1/' -e '/^ID:/d'
```

- `gunzip -c` extracts the file to `stdout`
- `sed` collapses all lines into one, then removes all lines not starting with `ID:`, then extracts the ID from matching files, then removes the ID: line for non-matching files, so that it displays either the ID or nothing.

Credits due to https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252191/5148242 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/218094/124507 @DarkHeart

### Original

`grep` is still the appropriate option, but for the sake of the exercise, you can use `sed` for the finding, and `paste` for the `-B2` part:

```
zcat nogrep.gz | paste - - - | sed -e '/^[[:space:]]/d' -e 's/^ID:\([[:alnum:]]*\).*Warning - No Profile Data/\1/' -e '/^ID:/d'
```

- `paste` joins each group of 3 lines
- `sed` removes all lines not starting with `ID:`, then extracts the ID from matching files, then removes the `ID:` line for non-matching files, so that it displays either the ID or nothing.

Comment: can any one suggest how to solve this since OS does not support this commands

Comment: Did you try the updated version from @chaos?

Comment: Yes  its showing error in syntax

Comment: I edited a new approach in, using `tr` instead of `paste`. Can you please give it a go?

Comment: @Darkheart - where do you get that? HP-UX is one of the few *certified* Unices. This means it passed a battery of tests to prove it meets the POSIX standard. It could not have done so without `paste`.

Comment: Its not working .tr is not elligible options

Comment: Can anyone tell how to fo using find command

Comment: `find` works on file information (name, type, permissions, modification time, ...), but as far as I know, it has nothing to select files based on their content. I edited my edited answer with an attempt using `gunzip` and `sed` only. Can you try it?

Comment: Why do you look for *`ID`*? Won't you miss printing matches for any pair of lines before *`No Profile`* but which is *not* headed with *`ID`*?

Comment: @mikeserv: I can't find the appropriate comment anymore, but I remember Pooja claiming to be interested in the value of the ID field only. Edit: Found it here -> http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/217896/124507

Comment: @Emeric - in that case you could save yourself a lot of effort *(and many possible misses)* by doing `sed -ne'/^ *ID/!d;N;N;/No Profile/s/ .*//p'`. As is you're bound to miss any match if the sequence goes off - for example if there is a group of 4 lines in one group and 3 in another.

Comment: sed -ne'/^ *ID/!d;N;N;/No Profile/s/ .*//p' . Its not able to print value of ID

Comment: @mikeserv - Yes I am wrong - it does have paste and the original example does work on HP-UX (after replacing zcat). The edited version, however, does not: "sed: The label :a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g is greater than eight characters."

Comment: @DarkHeart - oh yeah, that syntax isn't POSIX. Pretty much any `sed` command which takes an arbitrary parameter *(such as `:`)* needs to be delimited by a newline.

Comment: @DarkHeart - what do you mean by *replace `zcat`*? It's a POSIX utility, too, but it isn't a base utility like `paste` - an system might get certified w/o it, but they'd need something that could do similar. Is that what you're talking about? Is there another command?

Comment: @mikeserv - Yes, this one I actually tested. As someone else pointed out, there is gzcat. `zcat file.gz
file.gz.Z: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 2):

#### *(hopefully)* the final product

---

```sh
find . -name \*.gz -type f -exec   gzcat {} +  |
sed -ne'/^ *ID:/h;/No Profile/!d;x' \
    -e's/^ *ID:\([^ ]*\).*/\1/p'
```

So that will recursively `find` all of the regular files rooted in the current directory with filenames which match the pattern `*.gz` and call `zcat` as few times as is necessary to iteratively uncompress every one in a single stream to `sed`'s stdin.

`sed` will scan its input for lines which are headed with the string *`*ID:`*. It will `h`old a copy if found, and next look for *`No Profile`* while `d`eleting all lines which don't match. When found `sed` will swap into hold space and try to trim an *`^ *ID:`* line to only the portion falling between the first `:` and next occurring *<space>*. If successful, `sed` `p`rints the results.

As [@DarkHeart points out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218089/how-to-print-the-before-lines-of-search-keyword-with-out-using-grep-in-a-gz-file/218096?noredirect=1#comment371737_218096) you will most likely have to alter the `zcat` command name to `gzcat` on an HPUX system, though.

---

#### variations

---

This would be all you need to search a single file for line pairs occurring immediately previous to a match for the string *`No Profile`*:

```sh
gzip -d <file.gz |
sed -e'1N;$!N;/\n.*No Profile/P;D'
```

That will just scan input three lines at a time. Each line is separated by a `\n`ewline in pattern space. As each `N`ew line is pulled in, the oldest is `D`eleted. If the regexp `\n.*No Profile` is ever matched in pattern space *(as it will be when it is the newest line in pattern space, and the following cycle when it is the second to newest)*, the oldest line is printed. And so you get the two lines occurring before *`No Profile`*. If you want to also print the line on which it is found...

```sh
gzip -d <file.gz |
sed -e'1N;$!N;/No Profile/P;D'
```

---

#### with `find`:

---

```sh
find . -name \*.gz -type f -exec zcat {} + |
sed -e'1N;$!N;/No Profile/P;D'
```

You can swap the `.` there for the name of some directory if you like. You can also add the *`\n.*No Profile`* bit to avoid printing the matching line. That command will recurse into all child directories of `.`. If that is not to your liking:

```sh
find . \! -name . -prune -name \*.gz  \
          -type f -exec zcat {} +     |
sed -e'1N;$!N;/No Profile/P;D'
```

If you are specifically looking for the leading *`ID`* field and only if can be found two lines prior to a match for *`No Profile`* you can do:

```sh
find . -name \*.gz -type f -exec zcat {} + |
sed -ne'/^ID/!D;/\n/!N;N' \
     -e's/ .*\n.*\n.*No Profile.*//p;D'
```

...which would print only the leading *`ID`* field as it might occur in any/all of the *`*.gz`* files `find` calls `zcat` to print and only if *`ID`* definitely occurs two lines before a *`No Profile`* match.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26331/discussion-on-answer-by-mikeserv-how-to-print-the-before-lines-of-search-keyword).